# Listview no desliza

Tags: xamarin, listview, scroll, xaml

En una Listview voy añadiendo elementos, pero cuando hay más elementos de los que permite visualizar la pantalla no hace *scroll*.

**Solución:** El error estaba en la propiedad IsEnabled, quería que las fotos no se pudiesen seleccionar pero no me había dado cuenta de que también deshabilitaba el Scroll.

Aquí la vista:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
            Margin="10"
            BindingContext="{Binding DatosBase}">
        <Button 
              Command="{Binding TakePictureCommand}" 
              Text="Tomar Foto" />
        <ListView
                x:Name="Fotos"
                IsEnabled="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Imagenes}"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image
                               WidthRequest="150"
                               HeightRequest="150"
                               Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Prueba poniendo en la propiedad de ancho y alto el valor wrap_content

Comment: ¿A qué control te refieres? He ido probando en varios y me pone que la cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. @denifersantiagofernandez

Comment: ¿Porque necesitas la ListView dentro del ScrollView? La listview tiene su propio scroll que te permite añadir elementos y recorrerlos. Al meter una lista dentro de un scrollview lo que haces es "anular" el scrolling de la lista, puedes recorrer el contenido del scrollview (si hubieran mas cosas) pero no el de la lista.

Comment: He eliminado el Scrollview y ahora es el propio Listview el que no hace scroll, he añadido el código por si es de ayuda. @Mulflar

Comment: El error estaba en la propiedad IsEnabled, quería que las fotos no se pudiesen seleccionar pero no me había dado cuenta de que también deshabilitaba el Scroll. Gracias por tu tiempo. @Mulflar